# Why is google and youtube slow for me and is there a way I can fix it?

Tags: networking, performance, ping, connection, youtube

I am wondering why specifically google and youtube are slow and if there is anything I can try to fix it

below I ping, google.com, youtube.com, superuser.com, and yahoo.com and you can see google.com and youtube.com time's are significantly higher than superuser and yahoo.com, and I can definitely feel the slowness when browsing youtube/google.

**I also tried restarting the router**

google.com ping

```
➜ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.80.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=352 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=119 time=349 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=362 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=119 time=350 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=358 ms
```

youtube.com ping

```
➜ ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com (142.250.176.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s37-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.176.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=75.9 ms
64 bytes from lga34s37-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.176.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=75.4 ms
64 bytes from lga34s37-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.176.206): icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=75.5 ms
64 bytes from lga34s37-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.176.206): icmp_seq=8 ttl=119 time=75.6 ms
```

superuser.com ping

```
➜ ping superuser.com
PING superuser.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=7.46 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=7.48 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=7.54 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=7.47 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=7.52 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=7.49 ms
```

yahoo.com ping

```
➜ ping superuser.com
PING superuser.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=7.46 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=7.48 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=7.54 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=7.47 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=7.52 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=6 ttl=59 time=7.49 ms
```

NS lookup output of youtube.com was requested in the comments below

```
❯ nslookup youtube.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 142.250.176.206
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:81c::200e
```

Comment: You should probably complain to your ISP unless you're running some non-standard setup that could be causing this

Comment: Yep, call up the ISP - Maybe try out a VPN and see if the speeds normalize. A workplace (or parental controls) might also throttle traffic to certain services, but it requires someone on your end to have messed around

Comment: @gronostaj tried on my laptop as well, same results

Comment: Provide the output of `nslookup youtube.com` for us.

Comment: @Ramhound Added to the OP

Comment: What DNS server Is your router configured to use?  Have you tried a different DNS provider than your ISP?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, I have not. I will look up how to do that and once I have done it will report back and tell you the results

Comment: I think DNS will be a dead end since the lookup is done once (at most) at the beginning of the `ping`. Startup times may be slow but the ping times are not affected. Out of curiosity, can you try `ping6` and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @Ramhound so I switched the DNS to 9.9.9.9 and it seems to be a lot faster, not as fast as normal, but definitely faster. google went from 350~ ms to 81~ ms

Comment: @doneal24 i'm not really familiar with that command and don't understand it by looking it up :(

Comment: `ping6 google.com` will give you response times using the IPv6 protocols instead of IPv4. Your browser may be using IPv6 depending on how the exact system is set up.

Comment: Also I called up my ISP explained basically what I explained in my post, and she said "Today is a holiday, so a lot of people might be on those websites (google and youtube)" I explained to her that there would be people complaining online and I found nothing of that. Basically she didn't know what to do and didn't really have any trouble shoot steps expect for restarting my router which I already did. (for context it is veterans day in USA).

Comment: @doneal24 ah okay, yeah I tried that at first and assumed I was using the command incorrectly due to the output. Here is the output `➜ ping6 google.com
ping6: connect: Network is unreachable
`

Comment: Though, I think the problem may be solved. After changing my DNS on the router to use 9.9.9.9, google and youtube are reporting a lot faster response times, and I can definitely feel it on the browser too